# Buscar ID entrelaçado (que seja mútuo), sql mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu possuo uma tabela com este formato

```
RELATIONS
-----------------
ID | ID_1 | ID_2
```

todas em **INT** e o `ID` é auto incrementável.

Ela está preenchida desta forma:

```
ID | ID_1 | ID_2
----------------- 
1  |  1   |  5
-----------------
2  |  5   |  1
-----------------
3  |  1   |  3
-----------------
4  |  3   |  6
-----------------
5  |  6   |  3
-----------------
```

Perceberam que existem IDS entrelaçados? O `1` e o `5` estão conectados tanto na primeira via quanto na segunda, o `3` e o `6` também mas o `1` e o `3` não, por que não são mútuas as conexões..

Como pegar os entrelaços (que sejam mutuos na primeira e segunda via) do id número `6`? ou do `5`, ou `1`?

Por exemplo eu quero obter o ID do entrelaço do ID `6`

```
ID_PROCURADO | ENTRELAÇADO
---------------------------
6            |  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seja isso:

```
select t1.id_1 as procurado, t1.id_2 as entrelacado
from teste t1
inner join teste t2 on t1.id_1 = t2.id_2 
                   and t1.id_2 = t2.Id_1
where t1.id_1 = 6
```

Devido ao `INNER JOIN` só vai retornar os entrelaçados.

### [SqlFiddle Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f9c2/4/0)

Comment: Ótimo! haha, como eu posso pegar o id do `entrelacado` para jogar em outra tabela? Tentei mas nao obtive exito, veja: `select U.*, t1.id_1 as procurado, t1.id_2 as entrelacado
from teste t1, users U
inner join teste t2 on t1.id_1 = t2.id_2 
                   and t1.id_2 = t2.Id_1
where t1.id_1 = 6 AND U.id = entrelacado`

Comment: Quando eu começo a mexer em algo primeiro eu trabalho com prototipos até passar pra versao final, nesse prototipo a tabela se chama teste sim, e funcionou perfeitamente, só gostaria que ele fosse a tabela `USERS` e relacionasse o `ID` com o `ENTRELACADO`, ou melhor dizendo `USERS.ID = ENTRELACADO`

Comment: você quer fazer um insert em outra tabela com o ID entrelaçado?

Comment: Um select no caso..

Comment: no meu exemplo é a coluna t1.id_2, ele sempre vai retornar o ID do entrelaçado

Comment: Sim, mas na query que montei e te mostrei acima, mesmo substituindo me retorna um erro do mysql

Comment: pq você tem que fazer u.id = t1.id_2 e não entrelacado

Comment: Continua dando erro.. Veja voce mesmo..

Comment: qual erro está dando?

Comment: faz `select * from users u where u.id in ( select t1.id_2 as entrelacado from teste t1 inner join teste t2 on t1.id_1 = t2.id_2 and t1.id_2 = t2.Id_1 where t1.id_1 = 6)`